# Get the list of apps capable of handling the photo upload intent to display in a View (bottom sheet view,dialog,dialog fragment)

Tags: android, android-intent, bottom-sheet, photo-upload, android-bottomsheetdialog

I'm trying to get the list of all apps installed on a phone capable of handling the photo upload intent,
I would like to be able to get access to the list of apps to display them in a View in my activity

please help!!

Comment: Are you sure that Intent exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is that intent?

I think it doesn't exist so that might not be possible.

[Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common) you can check all the implicit intent types.

Uploading a photo is something you do calling a web service.